# Dired: How exclude dot from sort

Tags: dired

Emacs 26.1, Windows 10. Dired+

Here some folder:

[image]

I want to reverse sort. So I press `s`

And here result:

[image]

I don't want to sort symbols: **dot** and **2 dots**.  I want to sort ONLY file names.
Is it possible?

Comment: Pressing s does not mean to reverse the sort.  See the documentation with {C-h k s} in a dired.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Set it per buffer: Use `C-u s SWITCHES <RET>` as documented in [Updating the Dired Buffer](https://www.gnu.org/s/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Dired-Updating.html) section of the info manual,
   take only `-l` as the swithes, which defaults to `-al`.
2. `(setq dired-listing-switches "-l")` sets it permanently.

Comment: But I want to see dots to can exit by arrow UP from folder. So I need to show dots, but exclude dots from sort. Is it possible?

Comment: Do you mean opening the parent dir by "can exit by arrow UP from folder"? If so, type `^`.

Comment: I don't want EVERY time to type "Use C-u s SWITCHES <RET>" -1 to hide dots. Is it possible to do this automatically?

Comment: I've updated my answer, actually it's also documented in the manual section I posted before:)